# Modifying Trigger to Exclude a Specific User

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

Looking for some advice on how to modify a trigger that writes changes to a database table. Anytime a particular field is updated, it writes a record to an audit table detailing the change: that it was an update, which table, what column, who, when, the old value, the new value, and an unique key.

The issue is that we have an interface that runs between two applications that also updates this table and every time it runs, it creates an entry in the table.  This is causing additional hundreds of thousands of rows/records daily and we only need the audit applied to real users, not the interface account.

I'd like to change this trigger so that if the user is "RMADMIN", the trigger is not fired if this account is used to update the table.  Is this possible? I have never worked with a trigger. Thanks,

```
if( update(ActualStartTime)) 
begin 
declare @ActualStartTimeOld datetime
declare @ActualStartTimeNew datetime
select @ActualStartTimeOld = ActualStartTime from deleted
select @ActualStartTimeNew = ActualStartTime from inserted
if(@ActualStartTimeOld <> @ActualStartTimeNew)
begin
insert into auditdetail (changetype, tablename, columnname, changewho, changewhen, previousvalue, newvalue, owneruniquekey, uniquekey) 
select 'UPDATE', 'PeopleStaffingDetail', 'ActualStartTime', system_user, getdate(), cast(del.ActualStartTime as varchar(50)), cast(ins.ActualStartTime as varchar(50)), ins.uniquekey, newid() from inserted ins, deleted del where ins.uniquekey = del.uniquekey 
end 
end
```

Comment: You can't prevent the trigger from firing, but you can put an additional IF condition on the first line.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I somewhat understand what you are saying, but I don't know how I would include that in the IF statement. Would it look something like `And If (system_user <> rmadmin)) begin`

Comment: Not clear to me if `rmadmin` is a *user* or a *login* but generally it would be this (no repeated `IF`): `IF (UPDATE(col) AND ORIGINAL_LOGIN() <> N'rmadmin') BEGIN...`

Comment: `rmadmin` is a login. I am testing out `if( update(ActualStartTime) and original_login() <> N'rmadmin')` to see if that works for me.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, it looks like your solution works.  Can't mark it as correct in a comment but if you answer the question, I'll be glad to mark it as correct.  Coincidentally, I found your article "Break large delete operations into chunks" before I posted this for something else I needed.  So thanks to you two times today.